# Is it possible to call the functions of an object, without prefixing the object name?

Tags: javascript

I was writing javascript code for performing mathematical calculations.
For many functions, I need to type something like `Math.log()` or `Math.PI` or `Math.sqrt()`

Is there a way to define the "namespace" or something so I can directly access all the functions defined in Math by just saying `log()`, `PI` or `sqrt()` ?

Comment: Yes, `var log = Math.log,`...,`PI = Math.pi,`...,`sqrt = Math.sqrt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is `with`

```
with (Math){
   console.log(sin(4));
}
```

inside of the `with(Math)` block, you can use the functions defined on Math such as `Math.log` `Math.sin` etc.

You can find out more about it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

As the comments point out, this is not always considered safe because of the likelihood of name clashes. These potential pitfalls are the same as statements such as `using namespace` in another language, except that not all objects were designed to be namespaces. So, use at your own risk, or assign the particular function to a variable as another answer suggests.

Comment: The `with` keyword is not always recommended. The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) go into more detail.

Comment: sure, but it does exactly what he asked for.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't downvote because it is a discouraged solution, as it does do exactly what the OP was asking for. It is appropriate to point out that the solution is discouraged, but it is not reason enough to downvote it IMHO.

Comment: I didn't actually assume that, it was aimed at whoever _did_ do the downvoting.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Feel free to edit my answer to make it better or suggest edits. I tried to clarify it so that pros/cons could be seen.

Answer (score 5):

Simply remove the (), and you can assign the function to a variable, then call the variable later.

```
var log = Math.log;
// ...
console.log("log of 5 = " + log(5));
```

Comment: Example `var log = console.log;` is invalid, it won’t work. You must call it like `log.call(console, ...)`, or use `var log = console.log.bind(console);`